If the integral of $f(t)$ is finite, then does $f(t) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$?
Suppose $f: [0, \infty) \to [0,1]$ is a uniformly continuous function. If $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(t) \,dt$ is finite, does that imply $\lim_{t \to \infty} f(t) = 0$?
My intuition tells me it is possible: If the integral converges, then the area under the curve decays eventually and since $f \geq 0$, $f$ has to converge towards zero.
What would a formal proof look like?

Yes. You can assume otherwise, so there is an $\epsilon>0$ and a sequence of times $t_n$ that go to infinity and for which $f(t_n)\geq \epsilon$ for all $n$. Then reach a contradiction. If it helps, you can assume WLOG that your $t_n$ values are spaced at least 1 unit apart, meaning $t_{n+1}\geq t_n+1$ for all $n \in {1, 2, 3, ...}$. The uniformly continuous assumption is crucial (the result does not hold without it).

@JairTaylor that was a mistake. I have fixed it though

"My intuition tells me it is possible: If the integral converges, then the area under the curve decays eventually and since $f \geq 0$, $f$ has to converge towards zero." - I would say your intuition is wrong, in so far as it doesn't seem to require uniform continuity, which is crucial per @Michael's comment above.  Just imagine a function with infinitely many 'spikes' that get thinner and thinner in such a way that the area under the curve converges. (will allow you to fill in the details.)

@JairTaylor correct. In my mind, such a function looks smooth (which is natural I guess) but I should have mentioned something that this is exactly characterised by uniform continuity so thank you for that.

@JairTaylor To be fair,  I think their intuition is just fine, as what they have described is basically the main idea of the solution. Yes, there are subtleties they haven't considered. A more trained intuition might warn about these subtleties, but you have to start somewhere.

@Arthur Well, fair enough. Maybe I should say the intuition can be 'misleading' rather than flat-out wrong.

@Michael thank you for the suggestion. while it makes sense to use your idea of a discrete sequence of $t$ values, i'm somewhat stuck on how to proceed with this. My goal is to show by contradiction that $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(t) ,dt \geq \int_{0}^{\infty} \epsilon dt$. Is this the wrong aim?

@Michael ok I think I have an idea. Intuitively by uniform continuity, every integral on the ball centered at each $t_n$ must be positive. I think that's a good starting point

@rainingbricks2000 I think you are converging on the right idea.  Maybe you can think about it for a while and then post an answer yourself. If you get stuck I can provide a hint. Cheers

@JairTaylor I think I have got the solution. I'll make a post about it, to see what you think.

@JairTaylor I just came up with a solution. Let me know what you think.

Otherwise, you have a sequence $(t_n)$ strictly increasing such that $t_n\nearrow \infty$ and $\epsilon>0$ such that $f(t_n)\geq \varepsilon$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Without loss of generality, you can suppose that $t_{n+1}-t_n\geq 1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. By using the uniform continuity, there is $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon/2$ if $|y-x|<\delta$. Then, suppose that $\delta<\frac{1}{2}$, from the two last facts, you have $f(x)\geq \varepsilon/2$ for all $x\in ]t_n-\delta,t_n+\delta[$, therefore
$$\int_{t_n-\delta}^{t_n+\delta} f(x)dx\geq \varepsilon\delta$$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. But $$\int_0^\infty f(x)dx\geq \int_0^{t_n+\delta}f(x)dx\geq \varepsilon\delta n$$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, but it contradicts that $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx<\infty$.

Can you explain how you got $f(x) \geq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$

since for $x\in ]t_n-\delta,t_n+\delta[$, $f(t_n)-f(x)\leq |f(t_n)-f(x)| \leq \varepsilon/2$ then you have $f(x)\geq f(t_n)- \varepsilon/2\geq \varepsilon- \varepsilon/2 =  \varepsilon/2$

By contradiction, suppose there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ and a sequence $\{t_n\}$ such that for all $n$, $f(t_n) > 2\epsilon$.
Without loss of generality, take $t_{n+1} \geq t_n + 1$. Then $1 \leq |t_{n+1} - t_{n}|$.
So taking $\epsilon$ to be such that $f(t_n) > \epsilon$, then by uniform continuity, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $t \in B_{\epsilon}(t_n)$, we have
$$
f(t_n) - \epsilon < f(t)
$$
Without loss of generality, $\delta < \frac{1}{2}$. Since $|t_{n+1} - t_{n}| \geq 1$, $B_{\delta}(t_n) \cap B_{\delta}(t_{n+1}) = \emptyset$. Hence
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum^{n}_{k=1} \int_{B_{\delta}(t_k)} f(t) dt \leq \int_{0}^{\infty} f(t) dt
$$
Now notice that
$$
2 \delta (f(t_n) - \epsilon) < \int_{B_{\delta}(t_k)} f(t) dt
$$
Also notice that $\liminf_{n \to \infty} f(t_n) \geq 2\epsilon > \epsilon > 0$
Since $f(t_n) - \epsilon > 0$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(t_n) - \epsilon > 0$, then $\inf_{k} \{ f(t_k) - \epsilon \} > 0$. Hence
$$
2n\delta \inf_k \{ f(t_k) - \epsilon \} \leq \sum^{n}_{k=1} \int_{B_{\delta}(t_k)} f(t) dt \leq \int_{0}^{\infty} f(t) dt
$$
$$
\infty = \lim_{n \to \infty} 2n\delta \inf_k \{ f(t_k) - \epsilon \} \leq \int_{0}^{\infty} f(t) dt
$$

I think you generally have the right idea but you are missing something and you lose me a bit at the end. When you have $f(t_n) > \epsilon$ and $f(t_n) - \epsilon < f(t)$ all that tells you is $0 < f(t)$ which doesn't help you much. Instead I would apply uniform continuity to find a $\delta$ for the choice of $\epsilon / 2$ rather than $\epsilon$ and then you can say $\epsilon/2 < f(t)$ on the balls and everything will go through.

@JairTaylor the point isn’t to show that $f(t) > 0$ the point is that if you know that $f(t)$ is bounded below by $f(t_n)-\epsilon$ strictly positive, and in addition, the limit of $f(t_n) - \epsilon$ is strictly positive, then taking an $n$-infimum value over every $f(t_n) - \epsilon$ must also be strictly positive. The crucial part is that the infimum value chosen is strictly positive, and you can do this if you know how the limiting structure of the sequence behaves

@JairTaylor I added some corrections just now.

@JairTaylor but yes I also see your point. Where my approach is wrong, is that I could have chosen an even smaller estimate for the uniform continuity and simplified my proof. Sometimes spotting these small things can happen to me and I had an Intuitive idea in my mind that I wanted to model the limiting behaviour of the curve as it decays (which is why I took an infimum approximation). I hope that explains to you why I took these steps

Your proof looks mostly correct now, except that you can't say that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(t_n) - \epsilon > 0$ because the limit might not exist.  I would just say that $f(t_n) - \epsilon > \epsilon$ for all $n$ implies directly that $\inf_n f(t_n) - \epsilon > 0$. Or just use $f(t_n) - \epsilon > \epsilon$ directly without mentioning the infimum.

The problem in the previous version was that $f(t_n) - \epsilon > 0$ was not enough to conclude that $\inf_n f(t_n) - \epsilon > 0$.  In general $x_n > 0$ does not imply $\inf_n x_n > 0$ (consider e.g. $x_n = 1/n$.)

@JairTaylor correct, claiming that $f(t_n) - \epsilon > 0$ is not enough to conclude anything about the infimum.

@JairTaylor Regarding the limit not existing, I should be able to repair it by taking the infimum limit instead.

Here is a proof by contradiciton.
Suppose that there is $\varepsilon_0>0$ such that for any $a>0$ there is $t_a>a$ such that $f(t_a)>\varepsilon_0$. Choose $0<\delta<1/2$ such that
$$|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon_0/2 \quad\text{whenever}\quad |y-x|<\delta$$
Let $t_1>1$ with $f(x_1)>\varepsilon_0$. Suppose $x_1,\ldots,x_N$ have been chosen. Then, there is $t_{N+1}>(N+1)\vee (t_N+1)$ with $f(t_{N+1})>\varepsilon_0$. Continue by induction to construct a sequence $(t_N:N\in\mathbb{N})$ with that $1<t_{N+1}-t_n$ with $f(t_N)>\varepsilon_0$. This means that if $|y-t_N|<\delta$,
$|f(y)|>\varepsilon_0/2$.
Then
$$\int^\infty_0 f>\sum_N \int_{B(t_N;\delta)}f(y)\,dy>\frac{\varepsilon_0}{2}\sum_N2\delta=\infty$$
